# Kibana search with numbers is not fetching data from elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elastic-stack

When I search with numbers in Kibana to get the data from elastic search, I am not getting any  results.

I have below message stored in elastic search. If I search with 5723243287337 or 234234535, I do not get any results. But if I search with PHOENIX or any other text, I am getting results from elastic search.

13-04-13,ST,FRTTH-01,Rialto,CA,PHOENIX,AZ,85053,2.32,6.22,5723243287337,234234535,SO,1

Is there any known bug or am I missing any configuration. Appreciate any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When indexing CSV data, it is better to define mappings for each of the fields. Otherwise, ES would try to guess the data type, and then do the indexing, leading to unexpected results. See [here](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-core-types.html) for explicit mappings.

Comment: I am using logstash to ship log files to elastic search through redis. Based on your response, I added below filter to the shipper configuration                                                                                                                          filter {
   mutate {
    convert => ["message","string"]
   }
}                                                                                                                                     After doing this, I am getting results when I search with numbers as well. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add quatation. Elastic search will treat "number" as a string, like other text.